# Why will my Python list not sum the values together?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

```
frames = []
frame_total = []
total = 0

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball two: '))


    frame_total.append([ball_one, ball_two])
    for frame in frame_total:
        frames.append(frame_total)
        b = sum(frames)
print(frame_total)
print(b)
```

This is my code. I cant work out why I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'` when I try and print out the sum of each array within the main array. any ideas?

the idea is to create a bowling game. you have 2 balls in every frame, ball_one and ball_two. after each frame, i append these 2 numbers to an array. so if ball_one is 8 and ball_two is 1. then it will add [[8, 2]] then the next go if b_1 is 4 and b_2 is 4 then it will look like [[8, 2], [4, 4]]. then I want to add 8 and 2 and 4 and 4 to produce. [[10, 8]]. and then finally the total of both of these, so 18.

Comment: maybe you'd want to append frame, not frame_total ?

Comment: still get that error though

Comment: yeah, because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so let's say you want to have frame_total.append(ball_one+ball_two) and correction i said you first time :)

Comment: Try inserting `print(frames)` right before the `sum(frames)` line to find out whether the type is what you think it is.

Comment: Edit your question to explain us what you wanna do :)

Comment: @ChrisMartin this prints out [[2, 3]] which is what i am expecting.  i think it is coz i am trying to add ints and lists together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try. You want to append each pair [ball_one, ball_two] into the frames. After that, get the sum per pair and store it in another list, say frames_total and finally display the sum of everything. Here's the code:

```
frames = [] # will contain raw results in each frame. (ex. [[8, 2], [4, 4]])
frames_total = [] # will contain total values in each frame (ex. [10, 8])
total = 0 # sum of everything

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball two: '))

    frames.append([ball_one, ball_two])

frames_total = [sum(frame) for frame in frames]
total = sum(frames_total)

print frames_total
print total
```

If you want to have the info printed after every turn, here's a slightly different code:

```
frames = [] # will contain raw results in each frame. (ex. [[8, 2], [4, 4]])
frames_total = [] # will contain total values in each frame (ex. [10, 8])
total = 0 # sum of everything

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball two: '))

    frames.append([ball_one, ball_two])
    frames_total.append(ball_one + ball_two)
    total = sum(frames_total)

    print frames
    print frames_total
    print total
```

Answer (score 1):

- You keep defining `b` in each iteration of the `for` loop.  You should wait to define it until you actually need it.
- You keep appending `frame_total` to `frames` instead of `frame`.
- You try to find the sum of a list of lists instead of all the numbers inside each list.

Your updated program:

```
frame_total = []

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball two: '))

    frame_total.append([ball_one, ball_two])

print(frame_total)
print(sum(sum(sub) for sub in frame_total))
```

If you don't like generator expressions:

```
frame_total = []
total = 0

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(raw_input('Enter the score of ball two: '))

    frame_total.append([ball_one, ball_two])
    total += ball_one + ball_two

print(frame_total)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it as follows:

```
frames = []
frame_total = []
total = 0

while len(frames) < 2:
    ball_one = int(input('Enter the score of ball one: '))
    ball_two = int(input('Enter the score of ball two: '))


    frame_total.append(ball_one)
    frame_total.append(ball_two)
    b = 0
    for frame in frame_total:
        frames.append(frame_total)
        b = b + frame
print(frame_total)
print(b)
```

Comment: what's that ] supposed to do ?

Comment: I need it in an array of arrays though for what I am trying to achieve

Comment: cool this works but is there not a way to do it to keep them in an array of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

> sum(iterable[, start])
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from
>   left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The
>   iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not
>   allowed to be a string.

You are calling sum with a list of list. And since you have not supplied `start`, it is zero by default. So it basically tries to add an int and a list.

Try running `0 + [1,2,3]` and you will understand what your error is.

Comment: so how would this look in my code? i am unsure what the start would be?

Answer (score 0):

Your `frame_total` has one element, and it is `[ball_one, ball_two]`. When you append `frame_total` to `frames`, `frames` now has one element and it is still `[ball_one, ball_two]`. When you sum(frames) it will raise a `TypeError` because `frames` element is a `list` not an `int`.